# Change Windows 7 file permissions from command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions

How can I change Windows 7 file permissions using the command prompt?

I want to change permissions in program files, but `cacls` is not working for me.

Comment: similar problem has been answered here: http://serverfault.com/a/533848/69330

Answer (score 22):

`cacls` is depcriated in Windows 7. You need to use `ICACLS` instead of `cacls`.

```
ICACLS "filename" /grant "Users":F
```

This command is granting the privileges.

Answer (score 7):

To change permissions, use an administrator account on that machine to run `CACLS`. If you have UAC enabled, you may have to elevate the command prompt first by right-clicking on it and choosing "Run as Administrator".

You can use `cacls` as follows:

```
CACLS files /e /p {USERNAME}:{PERMISSION}
```

Where,

```
* /p : Set new permission
* /e : Edit permission and kept old permission as it is i.e. edit ACL instead of replacing it.
* {USERNAME} : Name of user
* {PERMISSION} : Permission can be:
      o R - Read
      o W - Write
      o C - Change (write)
      o F - Full control
```

For example, to grant your user account full (F) control to `files`, you would use the following command (typed in an elevated Windows command prompt):

```
CACLS files /e /p %USERNAME%:f
```

Read complete help by typing following command:

```
cacls /?
```

Answer (score 4):

If, for any reason, files have become disassociated with the administrator account in Windows 7, using ICACLS will NOT restore them.

You are forced to manually click EACH file, one at a time, and select *Properties > Security tab > Advanced button > Permissions tab > Continue button*.

If enabled, approve UAC prompt for Permissions Editor for Files and Folders and Uncheck *Include inheritible permissions from thsi object's parent*. Click the *Remove* button when prompted, then re-enable *Include inheritible permissions*, click *OK*.

This will restore your accesss to the file.

How can this be accomplished against an entire folder or set of files? Using `ICACLS *.* /RESET` does not work; it ends in error "Access is denied" for the files in question.

Comment: This is not a forum, so if you have a new question, please ask a new question using the big button above.

Comment: In think "Some User" information is important. I ended-up in this page looking for a way to fix bad permissions and his/her info was very relevant. But, since "Some User" post does not answer th PO question, this should be a comment or question instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

take ownership of the folder/files first then you work operations on same.

http://www.faqforge.com/windows/take-ownership-of-a-file-or-folder-by-command-in-windows/

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please include some of the information from the link in your answer using the built-in `> blockquote` syntax.

Comment: This answer is about as helpful as  *"The solution to your problem is here: [http://google.com](http://google.com)."*  ‎

Answer (score -1):

you need to run `cacls` with administrator right in order to change permission in program files...

Comment: how to run cacls as administrator using command itself?

Comment: ...and how would a person go about doing that?

Answer (score -1):

> **icacls "File/folder_name" /grant "USER":F /t**:
>   will provide full access to the user specified as"USER" to the file or folder specified. The /t allows traversal to its sub-folders and files and provides the permission

Comment: iI you ever return to the site, please see [answer].