# File Permission change in Windows 7

Tags: windows, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Windows 7 file permissions from command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/222256/change-windows-7-file-permissions-from-command-prompt)

How can I change file permissions in Windows 7 using a command?

Answer (score 1):

Windows comes with a special command line utility called `CACLS`.

You can use it as follows:

```
CACLS files /e /p {USERNAME}:{PERMISSION}
```

Where,

```
* /p : Set new permission
* /e : Edit permission and kept old permission as it is i.e. edit ACL instead of replacing it.
* {USERNAME} : Name of user
* {PERMISSION} : Permission can be:
      o R - Read
      o W - Write
      o C - Change (write)
      o F - Full control
```

For example grant Betty Full (F) control with following command (type at Windows command prompt):

```
C:> CACLS files /e /p betty:f
```

Read complete help by typing following command:

```
C:> cacls /?
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me.  Additionally, cacls works with user groups as well (just replace betty with the group name).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **takeown** command.

Have a look at the following articles:

[Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(WS.10).aspx)

[Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/29528-help-takeown-command.html)