# Cascade ownership and security permissions - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, permissions

I have a similar problem to that answered in [This Question](https://superuser.com/questions/210993/lack-of-permission-to-open-user-folder) however, since I need to do this to a large number of directories and sub directories I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to cascade the permissions down from root to file levels. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Click on the start button and then type `cmd` now right click on the `cmd` appear in the list and run it as **ADMIN** using the option **Run as Administrator**. Or you can use the shortcut key after typing the `cmd` press the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>**. Now typr the following command

> takeown /f (foldername) /r /d y

If the operation was successful, you should see the following message:

> SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "**foldername**" now owned by user "**Computer Name\User name**".

Then to assign the Administrators group Full Control Permissions for the file, you may use the `ICACLS` command. Use this syntax:

> icacls (foldername) /grant administrators:F /T

The `/T` parameter is added so that the operation is carried out through all the sub-directories and files within that folder.

For more help you can read this [article for vista](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tims/windows-vista-secret-11-deleting-the-undeletable).

Answer (score 1):

The command line programs `takeown.exe`, `icacls.exe` and `cacls.exe` can do what you want. As you don't say exactly what you need to do the concrete command line parameters are difficult to forsee.

The following questions may also help you:

- [recursively change owner windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/116625/recursively-change-owner-windows-7)
- [Change Windows 7 file permissions from command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/222256/change-windows-7-file-permissions-from-command-prompt)

Comment: `cacls` now called `icacls` in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, updated my answer. Anyway cacls.exe is also still part of every Win7 installation.

Comment: Yes but when you type it then command line will warn you as I've experienced :)